# Why is quantum gravity so tough to be proved experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-gravity, estimation, physical-constants, order-of-magnitude

A great deal of particle physics experiments are going on in CERN and similar experimental labs and their study is based on quantum field theory? But I could not understand why quantum gravity is so tough to be proved experimentally?

Comment: Because the Health and Safety Officer vetoed the "create a miniature black hole" proposal and the Ethics Committee would not sign off on a second Big Bang :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons. The first is that we don't yet have any rock-solid theories of quantum gravity. The second is that the nascent theories that we do have all suggest that gravitons (the gravitational equivalent of photons) have an extremely, extremely, extremely small individual effect on spacetime, so detecting them is well-beyond our current capabilities. To see this, think of the experiments that have recently been performed at LIGO. To observe gravitational waves arising from the collision of black holes- a massive event- we have had to build equipment that has been capable of detecting a change in spacetime dimensions smaller than the size of a proton. A single graviton would   represent an inconceivably smaller effect still.

Comment: BICEP2 experiment some time ago thought they had found the signature of gravitons but it turned out it was cosmic dust contamination. https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.6.3.20190326a/full/ , and they were talking of the inflation era of the uiverse gravitons.